# Is there a way to count occurrences of a specific value for unique columns in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and have a dataframe (cn_data2) with several duplicated columns. It looks something like this:

```
Gene breast_cancer breast_cancer breast_cancer lung_cancer lung_cancer 
myc     1                 0         1                1        2
ARID1A  0                 2         1                1        0
```

Essentially, the rows are genes and the columns are different types of cancers. What I want is to find for each gene the number of times, a value (0,1,or 2) occurs for each unique cancer type. 
I have tried several things but haven't been able to achieve what I want. For example, `cn_data2$count1 <- rowSums(cn_data == '1')` gives me a column with the number of "1" for each gene but what I want the number of "1" for each individual disease.

Hope my question is clear!I appreciate any help, thank you!

> 

```
structure(list(gene1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("ACAP3", "ACTRT2", 
"AGRN", "ANKRD65", "ATAD3A", "ATAD3B"), class = "factor"), glioblastoma_multiforme_Primary_Tumor = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), glioblastoma_multiforme_Primary_Tumor.1 = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1), glioblastoma_multiforme_Primary_Tumor.2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), glioblastoma_multiforme_Primary_Tumor.3 = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), glioblastoma_multiforme_Primary_Tumor.4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

Comment: Please use the full dput output for 3 rows  If you show only a part, I can't copy/paste and reproduce it as it gives errors

Comment: I am storing the dput output in a text file and this is what I'm getting. I might be making an error somewhere. I apologize and I'll check again.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay for such a simple task. I figured out that the gene column had 24766 levels that didn't drop even when I subsetted the original data frame and that's why I got a huge output from dput even for 3 rows and columns. I have posted the correct output now. Thank you again for your patience and help.

Comment: thank you so much, I got the code that you provided to work @akrun

Comment: Glad that it is working for you